# Python save Stream File to Local File

Tags: python, web-scraping, streaming, vlc

I'm working on a Python scraping project for politician videos. I have isolated this link (and others like it):

http://vod.europarl.europa.eu/wmv/nas/nasvod02/vod0804/2014/wm/VODUnit_20140414_20110100_20125200_63884a681455e14a75888c.wmv

It downloads what looks like a streaming video file, but it's only 295 bytes, and will play in VLC only. Is there a way to save that url in Python to an actual local video file?

I've opened the file with Notepad++, and the included URLs either download the same file, or result in an error, but the file itself plays after buffering with VLC.

Thank you so much in advanced for any insight!

Update: I've been trying everything I can think of to find out the actual location of the video, the full 1:50 video should take up at least a few mb...

Perhaps if someone knew how to see the source VLC uses to get the video, the 2 links in the stream file are not useful (at least to me so far). Could there be a redirect at some point?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but my issue is more about getting this stream file saved into an actual offline video, not simply downloading the stream link through Python.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Unfortunately I can't help.  You just need to store the file in the memory and use something like regex to parse the values and I don't know regex.

Comment: Here is an re that might help: `http://[\w|-|.|_|~|:|/|?|#|\[|\]|@|!|\$|&|'|\(|\)|*|+|,|;|=]+\.asf` https://regex101.com/r/3HvuqB/1